# How to easily increment values for a key inside a Map

Tags: javascript

If I use object literal as a map, I can simply do: `obj[key]++`, but for a map created through `new Map`, right now I had to do the follows:

```
let currentVal = myMap.get(key);
myMap.set(currentVal + 1);
```

Which is a lot of typing and no where near elegant. I read up on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map but there doesn't seem to be an example that covers my use case.